# ts enum not working Argument of type '"MALE"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Gender | (() => Gender | null) | null

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I want to use ENUM but I got this error message:

```
Argument of type '"MALE"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Gender | (() => Gender | null) | null
```

Code:

````
enum Gender {
  MALE = 'MALE',
  FEMALE = 'FEMALE',
};

  const [gender, SetGender] = useState<Gender | null>('MALE');```
````

Comment: An enum is really not an ideal choice for gender these days....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an `enum`, so instead of using string `'MALE'`, use `Gender` to reference the enum variable.

```
enum Gender {
  MALE = 'MALE',
  FEMALE = 'FEMALE',
};

const [gender, SetGender] = useState<Gender | null>(Gender.MALE); // valid code
```